# Jaxb omit timezone

Tags: java, jaxb

I have Date field in my class marked with jaxb annotation.

```
@XmlElement(name = "startTime")
public Date getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}
```

But in the result i get startTime wtihout timezone  even if it have it in zoneinfo.

So after setting it like this:

```
startTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I get that kind of result in JSON

```
"startTime":"2016-05-25T17:22:23"
```

How can i get format like this : `"2016-05-25T17:22:23.848+06:00"` ?

Comment: Ok, hold on ... you start by asking about JAXB, but then you swerve into JSON. What are you actually asking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Java8, have a look to the [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), and use the class `Instant` instead of `Date`.